# Переключение media_group по inline кнопке aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, callback

Есть функция отправляющая разбитый по 10 изображений список через send_media_group, на данный момент она отправляет все media_group, за каждой из которых сообщение с прикреплённой клавиатурой. Как сделать так, чтобы отправлялось одно сообщение с первой группой, далее сообщение с клавиатурой и при нажатии "Предыдущая группа"/"Следующая группа" содержимое сообщения с media_group менялось на нужную группу.

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(commands=['list'])
async def qr_list(message: types.Message):
    media_list = []
    chunk_size = 10
    images = os.listdir(images_folder + '/' + str(message.from_id))
    for image in images:
        img = str(images_folder + '/' + str(message.from_id)  + '/' + image)
        media_list.append(img)
    num_chunks = ceil(len(media_list) / chunk_size)
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        start_index = i * chunk_size
        end_index = (i + 1) * chunk_size
        chunk = media_list[start_index:end_index]
        media_group = types.MediaGroup()
        for image in chunk:
            media_group.attach_photo(types.InputFile(image), qr_reader(image))
        await bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, media=media_group)
        buttons = [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Предыдущая группа", callback_data="previous"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Следующая группа", callback_data="next")
        ]
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите действие:", reply_markup=keyboard)
```